# import single site files and db to multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a multi site wordpress network using the instructions given **[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)** and by adding the foolowing code to wp-config.php

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

and as a result im able to add new site .Now i have a site which i have installed in another domain .I have all the backups including the db and wp-content folder.How can i move my existing wp install into the multisite network? Please help !! Thanks !!

Comment: The answer to your quesiton is easliy found on google. Please see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great article on how to do this on the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite).

As always, when moving from single to Multisite, you should check that your plugins are compatible before making any major changes.  This is also documented in the linked article.